# Operadores lógicos en java igual y diferente

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con los operadores lógicos en java la verdad super raro y no se por que.

Estoy validando campos vacíos y mi problema es que si le digo, si es igual a vació deme un mensaje que hay campos vacíos pero aun así se va por el `else`, luego hice si es diferente a vació y aun así se va por el `else`. La verdad no entiendo.

También lo use así y me pasa lo mismo diferente para que haga lo que deseo pero aun así se va para el `else`.

```java
if((!"".equals(nombre)) || !"".equals(caracteristicas) || !"".equals(comentdir)))
```

Mi código es el siguiente.

```java
String nombre = request.getParameter("txtnombre");
String caracteristicas = request.getParameter("txtcaract"); // Características de la tarea
String comentdir = request.getParameter("txtcoment"); // Comentarios del director

if (!"".equals(nombre) || !"".equals(caracteristicas) || !"".equals(comentdir)) {
    msj.setMsjtareas("No ingreso datos datos.");
} else {
    tareas.setNombre(nombre);
    tareas.setCaracteristicas(caracteristicas);
    tareas.setComentariordir(comentdir);

    daotarea.updateTarea(tareas, "Propiedades");

    msj.setMsjtareas("Datos actualizados");
}
```

Comment: Es importante confirmar que los campos, además de no vacíos, sean no nulos.

Comment: Lo hice asi y me aun se va por else. La verdad me esta aplicando la logica super diferente nose porque.
```
if (nombre == null) 
```

Comment: Incluso use isempty que eso significa es vació y aun así sigue saliendo por else.

Answer (score 1):

> > Estoy validando campos vacíos y mi problema es que si le digo, si es igual a vació deme un msj que hay campos vacíos pero aun así se va por el else, luego hice si es diferente a vacio y aun asi se va por el else. La verdad no entiendo.

El problema radica en la forma como estás comparando los valores en la condición.

Por ejemplo:

```
!"".equals(nombre))
```

La condición de arriba dará como resultado un `true` y al momento de usar el operador de negación, dará `false`, haciendo que la condición nunca se cumpla y por esa razón, no se ejecuta ninguna instrucción del bloque `if`.

Para hacerlo más explicito, el código de arriba es equivalente a:

```
"".equals(nombre) == false
```

Es decir, por más que se detecte que el campo está vacío, la condición jamas se cumplirá porqué arrojará un `true`y por ende no coincide con `== false`. Sin embargo, si el campo no llegara a ser vacío, se cumplirá la restricción y te mostrará el mensaje de error.

La **solución** a tu problema es quitar el operador de negación y tu condición quedaría de esta manera:

```
if(("".equals(nombre)) || "".equals(caracteristicas) || "".equals(comentdir)))
```

De este modo no tendrás ningún error lógico.

Con respecto a:

> > Incluso use isempty que eso significa es vació y aun así sigue saliendo por else.

Es el mismo problema.

Si tenemos el siguiente código:

```
!nombre.isEmpty()
```

Tendremos el mismo error lógico, porqué el método `isEmpty` retornará `true` si el texto llegara a estar vacío y al momento de negarlo, la condición dará como resultado un `false`, haciendo que la restricción nunca se cumpla.

**Solución:**

```
if(nombre.isEmpty() || caracteristicas.isEmpty() || comentdir.isEmpty())
```

El problema de estos métodos es que solo te servirán para detectar únicamente campos vacíos, es decir, con longitud de `0`, sin embargo, no comprobará si el campo de texto tiene solamente espacios.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Program 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
        String a= "   ";
        System.out.println(a.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("".equals(a));
    }
}
```

Los resultados por pantalla son: `false`. Básicamente los métodos no detectaron que la cadena en realidad tiene únicamente espacio y por ende, esto indica que la cadena está vacía (visualmente para el usuario si lo es).

Una solución sencilla es usando el método [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) de la clase `String`. Esté método elimina los espacios iniciales y finales de la cadena y retorna una nueva referencia de objeto (de tipo `string`) con la cadena modificada (sin los espacios).

Entonces el código quedaría de esta manera:

```
if(nombre.trim().length() == 0 || caracteristicas.trim().length() == 0 || comentdir.trim().length() == 0)
```

Y de este modo, por más que escriban en el campo puros espacios, el método `trim()` lo eliminará y retornará un nuevo objeto, en la cual podremos verificar la longitud de la nueva cadena modificada, si es `0`, es porqué el campo en realidad estaba vacío, de lo contrario, no lo es.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa pero creo que lo estas escribiendo mal "segun yo", necesitarias declarar el operador de la siguiente manera para que reconozca si es vacio o no

```
if(nombre.equals("") || caracteristicas.equals("") || comentdir.equals("")){
    msj.setMsjtareas("No ingreso datos datos.");
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Dark, así lo hice tan bien pero me pasa lo mismo lo hice de todas las maneras que conozco solo que no las puse todas pero aun así me aplica la lógica al contrario

Comment: trata de imprimir los datos que estas recibiendo para ver si es que si vienen vacíos (imagino que es un proyecto de jsp) puede que en realidad no sea asi y por eso siempre se este brincando esa comprobacion, porque a mi nunca me a pasado algo asi
Aqui estaremos para ayudarte en lo que necesites

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en las condiciones de tu declaración if.
Vamos a analizarla...

```
if (!"".equals(nombre) || !"".equals(caracteristicas) || !"".equals(comentdir))
```

El formato "".equals(nombre) no es habitual, pero es correcto.

De todas formas estas diciendo:
- Si nombre no es "" 
o
- Si caracteristicas no es ""
o
- Si comentdir no es ""
Imprimir "No ingreso datos datos."

De manera que tienes un error lógico (el programa no hace lo que quieres)
Para solucionar esto deberías eliminar las negaciones de cada condición (El '!')